# dyld: Library not loaded when using gm module with ExpressJS

Tags: express, imagemagick, runtime-error

I'm trying to use the [gm module](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) with ExpressJS to resize images on the server. The resize wasn't working as expected so I changed my code to just console.log a value, which I could immediately see was giving me an error. I installed ImageMagick with Homebrew.

**CODE:**

```
var gm = require('gm')

...

gm('uploads/4d03e739a7302fc7f68d022339205dee.JPG').filesize(function(err, value){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
})
```

**FIRST ERROR:**

```
   { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

So, I did some Googling and read that I should change

```
 var gm = require('gm')
```

to

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true })
```

Now I'm getting this error, which I can't find anything about:

```
 { [Error: Command failed: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
 ] code: null, signal: 'SIGTRAP' }
```

I've tried uninstalling ImageMagick, updating Homebrew and reinstalling. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling freetype and running brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question...the answer was difficult for me to find so maybe this will help somebody.

Looks like there is a problem with Homebrew's bottled build of ImageMagick.

Uninstalling ImageMagick and reinstalling with the --build-from-source flag did the trick for me.

```
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12099